# Permissions of CIFS Mounts

Tags: permissions, mount, cifs

I have some sensitive data on a network share hosted on a Windows machine (drive D on mymachine.mywork.com) that I need to mount, as follows:

`sudo mount -t cifs mymachine.mywork.com :/D /mnt`

Will other users of the machine be able to view or modify my mounted network share? If so, how would I go about restricting all access to myself only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could try doing is burying the mount point somewhere in a directory that only you can get to.  So, if your username is 'bob', then try something like this:

```
mkdir -p /home/bob/securedir/mnt
chmod 0700 /home/bob/securedir
```

and then modify your mount command from above to this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs mymachine.mywork.com :/D /home/bob/securedir/mnt
```